# "posta" e "stazione" sono etimologicamente legate?

Tags: etymology

Passando vicino alla stazione ferroviaria ho notato un vecchissimo cartello indicante "impostazione" che si riferiva ad un ufficio postale ora dismesso. Ho riflettuto sul fatto che è abbastanza naturale che alla stazione ci sia un ufficio postale e mi chiedevo se l'assonanza "stazione" - "impostazione" fosse casuale o meno.

Mi sembra di capire che "stazione" deriva da "stare" e si riferisce ai punti in cui fermarsi durante un viaggio (prima per far riposare i cavalli, ora per fermare i treni). Mi pare anche di capire che "stazione" si può anche dire "posta", con la stessa etimologia, come in "fare la posta".

"Impostazione" invece sembra derivare da "imporre" cioè "mettere sopra". Qui, con molti dubbi, mi pare di capire che la "posta" sono le lettere che vengono messe da qualche parte (in una cassetta?) per essere inviate.

C'è un legame con il fatto che la "posta" per viaggiare deve essere portata alla "stazione"? Oppure l'affinità delle due parole è puramente casuale?

Comment: La locuzione *stazione di posta* era abbastanza comune.

Comment: Quindi si potrebbe dire "posta di posta" dove le due parole hanno etimologia diversa...

Comment: Che intendi con “posta di posta”? “Posto”, “posta”, “porre”, “postazione” etc. sono tutte contigue etimologicamente e risalgono a *ponere*.

Comment: Da qui http://www.etimo.it/?term=stazione mi pare di capire che *stazione* è contiguo a *casa di posta*

Comment: Emanuele, temo che tu ti stia confondendo. La parte «Fermata in un luogo; e quindi Casa di posta...» etc. è la definizione di “Stazione”, la spiegazione delle sue diverse accezioni. La parte etimologica è quella che precede, in cui si mostra appunto che deriva dal latino *stare*, passando per *statio(nem)* e così via.

Comment: Ok... quindi nella locuzione *stazione di posta* la *posta* non si riferisce allo smistamento delle lettere anche se ha la stessa etimologia. Si tratterebbe invece di un rafforzativo dello stesso concetto, tipo: "posto in cui fermarsi".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, non c'è alcun legame etimologico.

Semplificando, come si può verificare in qualunque dizionario: “posta” (e derivati) deriva dal latino *ponere*, “porre”, mentre “stazione” deriva dal latino (e italiano) *stare*. Come vedi, non c'è niente in comune.

Comment: Ma infatti ho consultato il dizionario, pensavo si capisse dalla formulazione della domanda. Cercavo infatti una conferma.

Comment: Scusa, intendevo la parte della voce di un dizionario dove viene fornita l'etimologia del termine.